# To exact revenge or vengeance?

Tags: meaning, expressions, phrase-requests

We are in the midst of a family disagreement about whether the correct phrase is

> to exact **revenge**

or

> to exact **vengeance**.

We could use a definitive answer (if one exists) or, at least, your guidance/best guess as to which one is preferred.

Comment: We ask that you do research before asking for expert help, and include your prior research in the question. Thanks.

Comment: @MετάEd: I'm happy to accept that consulting NGrams, etc., isn't required before asking. Googling [exact revenge exact vengeance](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=exact+revenge+exact+vengeance&oq=exact+revenge+exact+vengeance&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3j61.4508j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) doesn't produce anything obvious, and I don't see dictionaries helping much. If you closevoted, I think that was a bit ott.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Might want to take that to chat or meta. Comments are for offering constructive suggestions to the OP.

Comment: @MετάEd: Surprisingly, [I've never done this before](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/9237/how-much-prior-research-is-expected?tab=general), but hopefully there it is. If not, [maybe this is it](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9237/how-much-prior-research-is-expected)

Answer (score 5):

There is no "definitive answer". [Both forms exist](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=exact%20revenge,exact%20vengeance&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=)...

[image]

And as you can see, until a generation ago most people would have said *exact **vengeance*** was the "correct" version. But (particularly in the US), the pendulum has swung massively the other way. Rather than toss a coin though, I suggest *go with today's usage* rather than stay stuck in the past.

---

I will just acknowledge StoneyB's point that strictly speaking you normally *exact* things like *retribution* (because *exact* means *compel to be given, take forcibly*). But [he will have his revenge](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22have%20my%20revenge%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22have%20his%20revenge%22&oq=%22have%20his%20revenge%22&gs_l=serp.3...1146980.1149022.0.1149391.7.7.0.0.0.1.153.663.5j2.7.0...0.0...1c.1.17.psy-ab.unSwZmD83Lo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.47883778,d.d2k&fp=dc3bdb21c054a890&biw=1296&bih=930) implies if you can *have* it, you can *take/get it (from someone)*. By force, if need be.

Comment: Curses! You beat me! Foiled! But I shall have my revenge, which will be inflicted, not exacted!

Comment: And how do you get that dramatic horizontal compression?

Comment: @StoneyB: I'm not throwing away all the text I just wrote, so... By that argument, people shouldn't say [I will **have** my revenge](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22have+my+revenge%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). I think there's a limit to how precisely you can pin down valid usage. *And* I firmly believe there's an alternate universe identical to this one in every respect except that the Anglophones in that universe use the word **qwerty** for the flower we call a **rose** (their "versions of us" have exactly the same noses and sense of smell as we do, obviously! :)

Comment: ...I asked about charts on meta ages ago, but ended up [posting my own answer](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/a/1173/2637). I only know how to do my method - I couldn't do yours if I wanted to.

Comment: Thanks. Somehow you get a different display than I do. *Stat qwerty pristina nomine, nomina nuda tenemus.*

Comment: There's a marvelous Feynman lecture (Symmetry and Conservation Laws, I think) where he postulates aliens made of antimatter (they think they're normal, obviously). The bit that made me laugh out loud is [summarised on page 17 here](http://kicp.uchicago.edu/~odom/compton_files/compton_lecture_07.pdf). Given a universe big enough, and time, there must be a world somewhere out there with people writing *Stat **ytrewq** (well, you know what I mean! :) pristina nomine, nomina nuda tenemus.* (If you ever fall through a wormhole in cyberspace and meet one in the flesh - ***don't shake his hand!*** :)

Comment: What grammarians call a left-handed complement.